# Find the value of $\int_1^2\frac{3x-5}{x^3}~dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the value of

$$\int_1^2\frac{3x-5}{x^3}~dx$$

I'm not sure how to proceed, due to the difference in degree between $3x-5$ and $x^3$. I've tried the substitution $u = 3x-5$, giving the equality

$$\int_1^2\frac{3x-5}{x^3}~dx = 9\int_{-2}^1 \frac{u}{(u-5)^3}~du$$

However, this doesn't solve the problem I have of the difference in degree between the numerator and the denominator. I thought that perhaps partial fractions would make a difference, but the quadratic I had to solve was untenable.

Comment: Split it and find  integeration seperately

Comment: While I admittedly made a rather simple mistake here, I'm curious to know where the downvotes are coming from. Is this question not up to quality standards here, outside of the actual math?

Comment: OP, I'm not sure what the downvotes are from. You've demonstrated effort (albeit a simple mistake). I say: Keep up the good work and ask questions as you need to...

Comment: Why do you guys downvote ? The OP has posted the question with his/her attempts. I'm not sure why the downvotes are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{3x - 5}{x^3}
 =
 \frac{3x}{x^3}
 -
 \frac{5}{x^3}
 =
 \frac{3}{x^2}
 -
 \frac{5}{x^3}
 =
 3 x^{-2} - 5x^{-3}
\end{equation}
So the integration becomes
\begin{equation}
 3 \int x^{-2} - 5 \int x^{-3}
 =
 3 \frac{x^{-3}}{-3}
 -
 5
 \frac{x^{-4}}{-4}
\end{equation}
Can you take it from here ?

Comment: ... Somehow I completely convinced myself that I didn't know how to integrate negative powers of $x$. Thanks!

Comment: @TheAssistant: Just remember an exponent of $-1$ needs to be handled differently.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_1^2\frac{3x-5}{x^3}~dx=    \int_1^2\frac{3x}{x^3}~dx -5  \int_1^2\frac{1}{x^3}~dx$$

$$=3\int_1^2 x^{-2} dx -5\int_1^2 x^{-3}dx$$

You should take over from here and finish the problem.